# Accessing huge data from application

Tags: sqlite, sd-card

Before starting application, I just would like to know the feasibility here.

I have data around 15GB (text and some Images) stored in SQLite database of my SD Card, I need to access it from my application. Data will get increased on daily basis and may reach till 64 GB.

Can any one tell me limitations in accessing such huge database stored in SD card from the application?

Comment: That is a lot of data to not have permanent home

Comment: don't have any alternative. :(

Answer (score 1):

SQLite itself supports databases in that range like 16-32GB (it may start working slower, but it should still work).

However, you are likely to hit a limit of FAT32 maximum file size, which is just 4GB - and this will be tough to overcome. SQLite allows to use attached databases which allow you to split it into smaller chunks, but this is really cumbersome.

If you can format your SD card as ext4, or use internal storage as ext4, then you should not really have big problems.